# SSRS Random Error - There is no data for field at

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

We have a process that generates around 20,000 PDFs using SSRS as the backend.
The mechanism used to generate these is the [Report Execution 2005](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice?view=sqlserver-2016) API endpoint

We have just performed a run where occasionally a PDF would be generated missing some data, or the header or the body or the footer.

The break down of that was around 12,000 generated correctly, 1000 blank, 7000 data incorrect.

There doesn't seem to be a rhyme or reason for this, no pattern in the data or timings. In the logs we can see the following:

[image: SSRS Error Log]

We log all parameters used to execute these reports in a DB, so using this we went and re-run that report with the same parameters and it ran fine. We then went and took 100 of the random errored ones, ran them manually and they all worked fine.

My only straw left to grasp at is there is some caching or SSRS deep issue that is causing this.

If anyone has seen something similar or has an opinion on where to check next, would be much appreciated.

Comment: `There is no data for the field at position...` can be raised if the report references fields (columns) that aren't actually returned in the data set. Do any of the queries behind these reports return pivoted data? Do the columns returned in the pivot depend on the time-of-day? e.g.: will the report return less pivoted columns if the table(s) it queries hasn't yet received an import of data from another source "today"?

Comment: Another (more likely) scenario for the error is that a field was removed or the name changed in a table. There may be a `SELECT *` that prevents the initial field not found error.

Comment: This ended up being a REALLY weird issue. So we have an AO cluster setup. The stored procedure that generated the data ran on the head of the cluster and hit the primary node of the AO cluster. The SSRS was hard coded to hit the secondary cluster. This resulted in the data generated on the primary not being on the secondary at the time of render.